# Rails - Add a method to a textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, textfield

I'm trying to get the checkSwear method to run on each textfield before it's submitted..

I have basically this: (stripped down)

```
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'I love to ' %>&nbsp;
    <%= f.text_field :loveTo %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'I hate to ' %>&nbsp;
    <%= f.text_field :hateTo %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my controller I have:

```
  def checkSwear
    antiSwear.checkSwear(What goes here?)
  end
```

In routes:

```
  match '/check' => 'profiles#checkSwear'
```

Any help much appreciated!

(checkSwear is a separate gem; i.e. a separate problem! The what does here means what kind of variable is received from the form, to be put through the checkswear gem)

UPDATE:

Sorry for the camelcasing, I'm a Java developer studying Rails etc., old habits die hard. This is for a project. I'm supposed to be writing a small gem to do some ruby logic and apply it to something. The contents of the gem are:

```
module antiSwear

  @swearwords = ["f**k", "f***ing", "shit", "shitting", "lecturer"]
  @replacements = ["fornicate", "copulating", "poop", "pooping", "Jonathan"]

  def self.checkText(text)

    @swearwords.each do |swearword|
      if text.include?(swearword)
        index = @swearwords.index(swearword)
        replacement = @replacements[index]
        text.gsub(swearword, replacement)
      end
    end
    return text   
  end
end
```

:/

Comment: *Before* it's submitted? You'd need to make an Ajax call pre-submission. There are a variety of ways to do it, or use @hakunin's advice and do it as part of normal model validation.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be done in model validations.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :deny_swearing

  private
  def deny_swearing
    if AntiSwear.check_swear(love_to) || AntiSwear.check_swear(hate_to)
      errors.add_to_base('Swearing is not allowed.')
    end
  end
end
```

That said, if you insist on this being in controller, you can check `params[:profile][:love_to]` and `params[:profile][:hate_to]` to see what's been submitted.

P.S. In this example I used proper ruby naming conventions, since we don't use "camelCasing".

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this as part of validation? You can do it one of a few ways. You can run the check before save, via a custom validation method or override the setter directly. I show you the custom validation approach here:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :clean_loveTo

  protected
  def clean_loveTo
    errors.add(:loveTo, "can't contain swears") if antiSwear.checkSwear(loveTo)
  end
end
```

I'm assuming checkSwear returns a boolean here.

Comment: also your field names do not meet Rails conventions. loveTo should be renamed to love_to and hateTo should be renamed to hate_to

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an intersection on arrays, one of which is the source text split into words, then gsub the replacements in. You have to be sure to have a 1:1 relationship between the words and their replacements, in which case I'd suggest using a hash for your dictionary (coincidentally what hashes are sometimes called in other languages).

```
module antiSwear

  # var names changed for formatting
  @swears = ["f**k", "f***ing", "shit", "shitting", "lecturer"]
  @cleans = ["fornicate", "copulating", "poop", "pooping", "Jonathan"]

  def self.checkText(text)
    # array intersection. "which elements do they have in common?"
    bad = @swears & text.split # text.split = Array
    # replace swear[n] with clean[n]
    bad.each { |badword| text.gsub(/#{badword}/,@cleans[@swears.index(badword)] }
  end

end
```

You might need to futz with `text.split` arguments if the replacement gets hung up on `\n` & `\r` stuff.